# freeradius radacct update does not occur immediately

Tags: networking, openvpn, freeradius

I use freeradius and ldap and openvpn in my project.
when user disconnect from openvpn,radacct table does not update.
I need that acctstoptime updated immediately.
please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

We can not easily answer your question in its current form. You need to provide more information.

To help you debugging the issue, you need first to make sure radius accounting is enabled using the appropriate module (ldap, database, etc..).

One other option is to start freeradius server in the foreground in full debug mode using:

```
$ sudo freeradius -X
```

This can be done on a testing machine and watching for possible errors when you are making radius requests.

Comment: thanks @khaled.sorry for my bad english.i connect via openvpn from my win7 client to freeradius server that is in the ubuntu os.my external database for authentication is ldap.i use mysql for freeradius accounting information.when user connected to freeradius server,one record with the correct acctstarttime is added to radacct but my problem is that when my user disconnect from win7,its acctstoptime remains null and after a period another record is added to radacct with both acctstarttime and acctstoptime.Times in the both of them are correct but my problem is its update time.